# Does cloud servers access everywhere in the world

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, dedicated-server, online-game, real-time-multiplayer

I made a game with unity. Now I am make it online with darkrift2, Darkrift gave me a server, I need to put it to rented cloud server. I want access hole world. Should I put the server to multiple locations for access all the world, which i don’t want to manage with or When I put to one rented cloud server, will it do automatickly access to hole world? And you know there are companies that rent server, how can I understand that company is automaticly  access all of the world?

Comment: Define "hole world" ^^ You might have issues in countries like North Korea, China, etc

Comment: I want to reach as much country as possible, There can be couple of countries missing.

Comment: [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com) as basically everything nowadays? ^^

Answer (score 0):

When you rent cloud resources you can chose in which data-center they are hostet, at least with the big cloud providers. In the example of Amazon Web Services, they have [regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html) basically all around the world.

Certainly you can configure your VM to be accessible from anywhere in the world, but you have to take into account latency. For example if you host a server in us-east-1 (N. Virginia) you will experience latency in the order of at least 200ms in eastern Europe.

Another factor is if a countries politics will allow it.

Comment: I want to put a server app to one place, and it should access most of the countries, so i don't have to manage with puting server to multiple places, Is this possible?